# Partition a Queue for Parallel Processing

Tags: c#, .net, queue, task-parallel-library

I'm writing a server that is ingesting data from thousands of clients. I want to process this data in parallel, *but* data for each client must be processed serially, in order.

For example, if I have clients A, B, and C, I would simultaneously process data from all 3 clients, but only a single item at a time from each client.

My first attempt at this was to create a kind of partitioned queue, with a single `Task` consuming from each partition: `ConcurrentDictionary<string, BlockingCollection<T>>`, where the `string` is the client identifier. With this, I spun up a `Task` to consume from each client and kept them in a dictionary `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>`. The tasks are straightforward, and make use of `GetConsumingEnumerable`:

```
return Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var item in list.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        this.action(item);
    }
});
```

This works well, but only up to around 75 clients - after that, items-per-second performance drops rapidly, likely due to contention between the tasks.

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps using a smaller, fixed number of consuming threads that can somehow rotate which partition they are consuming from?

I haven't found anything useful in the .NET Framework itself, but I have a feeling it might be possible to leverage the TPL somehow?

**EDIT**
I am *not* asking simply how to process a single queue with multiple producers and a single consumer. Also, I'm not *only* interested in a TPL-based solution; I just thought it might help.

Comment: @GregoryNeal no, that's much simpler than my question; indeed, I give an example of a single-consumer in my question! Could you please remove this flag so my question doesn't get ignored or flagged as a dupe by others who haven't read the question?

Comment: @Cocowalla - It might help if you indicate whether these are connected or disconnected clients (thick vs thin). The solution for each one would likely take a considerably different approach.

Comment: @NightOwl888 in reality, the clients are sending messages to a message broker, and the server is consuming them. So the message broker client running on the server is adding incoming messages to the queue that I want to then process in parallel.

Comment: Suppose next item in queue is for client A, but there is already another item for client A being processed by one consumer. Should other consumers wait for that one to complete or they are allowed to skip this item and fetch next one (for another client)?

Comment: @Evk they can skip it and fetch another; the requirement is that we only ever process one message at a time for any given client - but we want to process multiple messages concurrently (for different clients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was getting sidetracked by thinking about having a separate partition for each client - what I've come up with is to partition into a fixed number of queues, based on the hashcode of the client ID (which is a GUID).

This has the advantage of giving me control over the level of concurrency, and is also simple to implement.

So my queues are defined like:
`Dictionary<int, BlockingCollection<T>> queues;`

And data is added like:

```
public void Enqueue(T val)
{
    var bucket = val.Id.GetHashCode() % this.maxConcurrent;
    this.queues[bucket].Add(val);
}
```

Comment: I know you solved your own problem already, but you might be interested in this docs article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, I did come across Partitioners when I was researching a solution, but I couldn't figure out how to actually customise *how* the data is partitioned. There don't seem to be many samples about - I'd be really interested to see a solution that uses a Partitioner to partition a `BlockingCollection` in a similar manner to my solution?

Comment: To create a customized partitioner in the way you want you just need to write a class that is derived from `Partitioner<T>`, throw a `new NotSupportedException()` in your `GetPartitions(Int32)` method, have `SupportsDynamicPartitions` return true, and then implement `GetDynamicPartitions()` so that every call to it returns a `IEnumerable<T>` of a specific client's data and don't ever give out a new copy of the same client's enumerable if the original enumerable has not yet been disposed of yet.